# handle exception from openFile in a optparse-applicative ReadM

Tags: haskell, monads, optparse-applicative

Using optparse-applicative, I'd like to have an optional argument, which should be a path to a file, or when not specified, `stdin`. The obvious choice here is to make this argument type `IO Handle` and when an argument is passed in use `openFile`. Here's what I have currently:

```
module Main where

import Data.Semigroup ((<>))
import Options.Applicative
import System.IO

data Args = Args { input :: IO Handle }

parseArgs = Args <$> argument parseReadHandle (value defaultHandle)
  where defaultHandle = return stdin :: IO Handle

parseReadHandle :: ReadM (IO Handle)
parseReadHandle = eitherReader $ \path -> Right $ openFile path ReadMode

getArgs :: IO Args
getArgs = execParser $ info (parseArgs <**> helper) fullDesc

main :: IO ()
main = run =<< getArgs

run :: Args -> IO ()
run (Args input) = putStrLn =<< hGetContents =<< input
```

The trouble with this is, we don't properly `handle` exceptions from `openFile` and instead rely on the default behavior for an unhandled exception (prints error and exits). This seems yucky.

I think the more proper way would be to return `Left` with the error message from `openFile`. The trouble is, `eitherReader` expects a `String -> Either String a` so we can't do something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Exception

parseReadHandle :: ReadM (IO Handle)
parseReadHandle = eitherReader tryOpenFile

tryOpenFile :: IO (Either String (IO Handle)) -> FilePath
tryOpenFile path = do
  handle (\(e :: IOException) -> return $ Left $ show e) $ do
    return $ Right $ openFile path ReadMode
```

Of course, you can see from the type of `tryOpenFile` that this won't typecheck. I'm unsure if what I'm asking for is possible, because it seems like the error message must be an `IO String`, because to get the error the IO computation must be performed. So at the least it seems you would need `eitherReader` to take a `String -> IO (Either String a)` or a `String -> Either (IO String) (IO Handle)`. From my basic understanding of them, it sounds like a monad transformer could be used here to wrap the ReadM (or the other way around?). But that's a bit deeper than my understanding goes, and I'm at a loss about how to precede.

Is there a way to accomplish `handle`ing an `IOException` in an optparse-applicative `ReadM`?

Comment: Instead of `data Args = Args { input :: IO Handle }` perhaps you need `data Args = Args { input :: Maybe (IO Handle) }`?

Comment: The simplest possible solution is to replace `IO Handle` with `Maybe FilePath` and to read from the file after your program arguments have been parsed. Your parser becomes `Args <$> argument (Just <$> str) (value Nothing)`, and you are free to deal with the existence/non-existence of the file in any way you like in e.g. `main`. This logic is not part of a parser anyways, and the type of the parser reflects this. You can always make `input` a parameter (i.e. `data Args a = Args { input :: a }`) and have a function `Args FilePath -> IO (Args Handle)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your approach is somewhat misguided.

You said: `"I'd like to have an optional argument, which should be a path to a file..."`

Ok, so how about something along the lines of `Maybe FilePath`? That sounds like it might be what you want here. Or an equivalent ADT:

```
data Path = StandardInput | Path FilePath
```

When you say, `"The obvious choice here is to make this argument type IO Handle and when an argument is passed in use openFile"`
 you're getting ahead of yourself.

Parsing from the command line should be about transforming the input to be parsed into data that's suitable for future use in your program. Don't worry about opening files at this stage, or handling exceptions if files don't exist, or any other ways in which you're going to *use* this data... Just worry about the question, did the user of my program give me a file path or not? That is, what data do I have? The other stuff is not (and should not be) `optparse-applicative`'s job.

So just build your parser for this datatype `Path`. It may be composed of parsers for each constructor. E.g.:

```
stdInputParser :: Parser Path
stdInputParser = ...

pathSuppliedParser :: Parser Path
pathSuppliedParser = ...

pathParser :: Parser Path
pathParser = pathSuppliedParser <|> stdInputParser
```

Anyway, once you run `execParser`, you'll be left with your `Path` datatype. So you'll pass that as the argument to your `run` function:

```
run :: Path -> IO ()
run StandardInput = ... use stdin here
run (Path filePath) = ... use openFile here, catch and handle exceptions if the file doesn't exist, etc.
```

Comment: I'm willing to concede that what I'm looking for is perhaps far fetched. I'd argue however that  But just for the academic exercise of mucking with monads, are you saying that the type of `eitherReader` makes it impossible to do any other sort of monadic computation?

Comment: My comment was about what you should do, not what you could do. You should use a validation library to validate your data, then pass your validated data to functions that perform monadic computations. Don't try to needlessly force monadic computations inside your applicative validators. Remember, the library is based around applicative computations - not monadic ones; yet the behavior you want is fundamentally monadic (i.e. to perform certain computations in the case of certain values, other computations in the case of other values). That's really outside the purview of optparse-applicative.